# zoom image within set bounds

Tags: android

I have an app where I have a surface view.  On this surface view I display up to two bitmaps at a time that are clips from a short movie.  I have this working fine, however I allow the user to zoom and pan the images/clips.  I would like to divide the screen equally so in a vertical orientation I would have one clip taking the top half of the screen and the other clip taking the bottom half.  Since this is one surfaceview there is no actual separation of these views.

Currently the second bitmap I draw if it crosses the imaginary boundary for screen real estate then it is overlayed on the other bitmap.  I would like to just chop off the parts of the image that cross the boundary, does anyone know how I can enforce this when drawing on my canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, i'll post the answer here in case anyone else comes across something similar.  What I am doing is something similar to the following.  I create new canvas objects to work with and a writable bitmap for those canvas objects.  I can then perform any drawing and transformations on the individual canvas objects, and then just draw those to my main canvas of my SurfaceView.

```
if(workingBitmap==null){
        workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        c.setBitmap(workingBitmap);
        workingBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        c2.setBitmap(workingBitmap2);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0,null);
    c2.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0,-100,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(workingBitmap, 0,0,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(workingBitmap2, 0,canvas.getHeight()/2,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters

```
     private float dx; // postTranslate X distance
     private float dy; // postTranslate Y distance
     private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
     float matrixX = 0; // X coordinate of matrix inside the ImageView
     float matrixY = 0; // Y coordinate of matrix inside the ImageView
     float width = 0; // width of drawable
     float height = 0; // height of drawable
```

change the

```
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == DRAG) { // movement of first finger

        //  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            //.
             matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                matrixX = matrixValues[2];
                matrixY = matrixValues[5];
                width = matrixValues[0] * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable()
                                        .getIntrinsicWidth());
                height = matrixValues[4] * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable()
                                        .getIntrinsicHeight());

                dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                dy = event.getY() - start.y;

                //if image will go outside left bound
                if (matrixX + dx < 0){
                    dx = -matrixX;
                }
                //if image will go outside right bound
                if(matrixX + dx + width > view.getWidth()){
                    dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;
                }
                //if image will go oustside top bound
                if (matrixY + dy < 0){
                    dy = -matrixY;
                }
                //if image will go outside bottom bound
                if(matrixY + dy + height > view.getHeight()){
                    dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;
                }
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            //...

    //              if (view.getLeft() >= -392) {
   //                   matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() -               start.x, event.getY()
     //                         - start.y);
        //
     //             }
        } else if (mode == ZOOM) { // pinch zooming
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 5f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                scale = newDist / oldDist; // thinking i need to play around
                                            // with this value to limit it**
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }

        break;
```