# Android ACTION_MOVE image set image scrolling bounds outside its parent

Tags: java, android, matrix, android-imageview, scale

I implemented ACTION_MOVE for ImageView which is bigger then its parent (FrameLayout). Now I'm trying to add some code to stop movement (both drag and pinch zooming) when at least one of Image edges is inside its parent (so it won’t show background of a parent).

I used the code like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656739/how-can-i-set-maximum-and-minimum-zooming-levels-for-image-in-android).

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        float newX = event.getX() - start.x;
        float newY = event.getY() - start.y;

        if (view.getLeft() >= -392){
            matrix.postTranslate(newX, newY);
        }
    }
    else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming
        float[] f = new float[9];

        float newDist = spacing(event);
        if (newDist > 5f) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            scale = newDist / oldDist; 
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
        }

        matrix.getValues(f);
        float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        if(scaleX <= MIN_ZOOM) {
            matrix.postScale((MIN_ZOOM)/scaleX,
                 (MIN_ZOOM)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
        } 
        else if(scaleX >= MAX_ZOOM) {
            matrix.postScale((MAX_ZOOM)/scaleX, 
                 (MAX_ZOOM)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
        }
}
break;
```

I tried many things, and I know similar questions had been asked already but non of them fit my need so far.

My best guess was to add code below but it looks like `mImageView.getLeft()`, `mImageView.getRight()` etc returns parents edges not the images.

In onCreate():

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = 
getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
float screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

and in `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

```
if (mImageView.getLeft() > 0 ||
    mImageView.getRight() < screenWidth) {
       matrix.postTranslate(0, newY);
       break;
}
else if (mImageView.getTop() > 0 || 
       mImageView.getBottom() < screenHeight) {
       matrix.postTranslate(newX, 0);
       break;
 }
 else {
        matrix.postTranslate(newX, newY);
 }
```

And this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mag_background">
    <TextView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewHeadingLabel">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="image to zoom"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution [hire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492939/zoom-image-within-set-bounds).

I reverse the checks so instead of not letting image to move outside layout I not letting image bounds to be move inside layout like this:

```
if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
    matrixX = matrixValues[2];
    matrixY = matrixValues[5];
    width = matrixValues[0] * (view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
    height = matrixValues[4] * (view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());
    dx = event.getX() - start.x;
    dy = event.getY() - start.y;

    //if image will go inside left bound
    if (matrixX + dx > 0){
        dx = -matrixX;
    }
    //if image will go inside right bound
    if(matrixX + dx + width < view.getWidth()){
        dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;
    }
    //if image will go inside top bound
    if (matrixY + dy > 0){
        dy = -matrixY;
    }
    //if image will go inside bottom bound
    if(matrixY + dy + height < view.getHeight()){
        dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;
    }
    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
}
```

However if you move zoomed image to the corner and then zoom out, it will show parent background until next touch event so problem is not fully solved.